# Increase size of circle in aromatic ring while retaining ring size

Tags: chemistry

Is it possible to increase the size of the circle in the aromatic ring (i.e. the circle is "closer" to the hexagon).

Example: [image: Desired size]

Current: [image: Current size]

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How do you produce the output currently? What is your code?

Answer (score 5):

It is not easy to scale the inner circle via the `scale` option since the scaled circle is not centered, but you could use a `\chemmove` command and draw the circle later. There is also the option `cycle radius coeff` which is set to 0.75 per default but can be changed to a larger number:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{**6(---(-OMe)---)}

\chemfig{**[0,360,scale=1.25]6(---(-OMe)---)}

\chemfig{*6(---(-OMe)---)}
\chemmove{\draw (cyclecenter1) circle[radius=0.8];}

\setchemfig{cycle radius coeff=0.875}
\chemfig{**6(---(-OMe)---)}
% or: \chemfig[cycle radius coeff=0.875]{**6(---(-OMe)---)}

\end{document}
```

[image]